# Trying to query data based on range of date but for only one time point

Tags: sql, sql-server, squirrel-sql

I am trying to query a MSSQL database through SQuirreL, which works if I just want all data through a range of timestamps. However, I would like to query a range of dates but for only one time point. I have been successful at performing this type of query in postgresql, but I am not as familiar with MSSQL sql queries.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >='06/04/19 00:00:00' AND 
(TimeValue(timestamp) BETWEEN '23:40:00' AND '23:55:00');
```

I can use the line of code to work if I select just a date or timestamp range, but once I add the time value I get no matching data even though I know it is there.
I am sure that I am just not doing the syntax correct, or for MSSQL there is different way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Add a line `Debug.Print SQLstring` after the query in the code. And Press `CTRL + G`. Now when you will run the code you will see the query that VBA is constructing and you can copy paste and check it in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

What query did you generate, when you didn’t receive data? I assume you did a mistake with “and/or”. The query you are looking for probably looks like the following:

```
`WHERE (TIME(timestamp) BETWEEN {t ‘12:00:00’} AND {‘t 14:00:00’}) AND ((DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN var1 AND var2) AND (DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN var1 AND var2))`
```

Comment: So I tried this and I get an error in SQuirreL:
Error: 'TimeValue' is not a recognized built-in function name.
SQLState:  S00010
ErrorCode: 195

Comment: @GregoryBoyle no clue what “TimeValue()” is supposed to do. Did you try “TIME()” instead?